# .net 2.0: getting all keys and values pairs from object, passed from JS

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I have a C# application in web page. Web calls my apllication via JS:

```
var data = {key1:value1, key2:value2};
app["methodName"](data);
```

So, in my app:

```
public void methodName(dynamic data)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair pair in data)
    {
        Debug.Log(pair.Name + ": " + pair.Value)
    }
}
```

But the problem is, I'm forced to use .net v2.0, and `dynamic` is not available.
Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.80).aspx disagrees with you. KeyValuePair was first introduced with the generic collections in .NET 2.0. Also, if you're using .NET 2.0, you're not going to do much with the `dynamic` type, because while you can use a newer compiler to target an older runtime, `dynamic` requires support from the runtime that shipped with .NET 4.0.

Comment: tnx for response. I'v edited question. Any Ideas how can I solve this without `dynamic`?

Comment: It would help if you also specified what your specific environment is. ASP.NET MVC? Web API? WebForms?

Comment: it's Unity3D application if simple html iFrame with some JS code

Comment: Ah, I see, so your C# code is running inside the Unity engine? I'm not familiar with it, but try declaring the parameter as a Dictionary<string, object> maybe?

Answer (score 0):

if you want the keys and values in javascript try this

```
Object.keys(data) ///will return the array of keys
```

Refer : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

hope this helps